# rewrite Hibernate query without huge list parameter

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

In my database I have a `zip` table with a `code` column. The user can upload a list of Zip codes and I need to figure out which ones are already in the database. Currently, I do this using the following Hibernate query (HQL):

```
select zip.code from Zip zip
where zip.code in (:zipCodes)
```

The value of the `:zipCodes` parameter is the list of codes uploaded by the user. However, in the version of Hibernate I'm using there's [a bug](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2166) which limits the size of such list parameters and on occasions we're exceeding this limit.

So I need to find another way to figure out which of the (potentially very long) list of Zip codes are already in the database. Here are a few options I've considered

### Option A

Rewrite the query using SQL instead of HQL. While this will avoid the Hibernate bug, I suspect the performance will be terrible if there are 30,000 Zip codes that need to be checked.

### Option B

Split the list of Zip codes into a series of sub-lists and execute a separate query for each sub-list. Again, this will avoid the Hibernate bug, but performance will likely still be terrible

### Option C

Use a temporary table, i.e. insert the Zip codes to be checked into a temporary table, then join that to the `zip` table. It seems the querying part of this solution should perform reasonably well, but the creation of the temporary table and insertion of up to 30,000 rows will not. But perhaps I'm not going about it the right way, here's what I had in mind in pseudo-Java code

```
/**
 * Indicates which of the Zip codes are already in the database
 *
 * @param zipCodes the zip codes to check
 * @return the codes that already exist in the database
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the list is null or empty
 */
List<Zip> validateZipCodes(List<String> zipCodes) {

  try {
    // start transaction

    // execute the following SQL
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE zip_tmp
    (code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL) 
    ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

    // create SQL string that will insert data into zip_tmp
    StringBuilder insertSql = new StringBuilder()

    for (String code : zipCodes) {
      insertSql.append("INSERT INTO zip_tmp (code) VALUES (" + code + ");")
    }     

    // execute insertSql to insert data into zip_tmp

    // now run the following query and return the result   
    SELECT z.*
    FROM zip z
    JOIN zip_tmp zt ON z.code = zt.code

  } finally {
    // rollback transaction so that temporary table is removed to ensure
    // that concurrent invocations of this method operate do not interfere
    // with each other
  }    
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to implement this than in the pseudo-code above, or is there another solution that I haven't thought of? I'm using a Postgres database.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the result of the operation? If your plan is update your db with the zipcodes that did not exist, then you could sort that out in Java. Query all zipcodes from your db, find the ones that are missing and insert those. In that way you do not need to query in this way.

Comment: @Hugo I need to return the Zip codes that don't exist to callers of this method, so this isn't an option

Answer (score 1):

Load all the Zip codes in the database to a List. And on the user inputed list of Zip codes do a `removeAll(databaseList)`.

Problem solved!

Comment: You can then also cache the method loading the zip codes, so you don't hit the db so often.

Answer (score 0):

Option D:
Loading all existing zip codes from the database (pagination?) and make the compare in your application.

Regarding your Option A:
I remember a limitation of the SQL query lenght but that was on DB2, I don't know if there is a limit on PostgreSQL.

Comment: I think the limit is in SQL IN statement. In Oracle there's a limit of 1000. I don't know about others though, but I believe there will be a similar limitation.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by option E? Are you just proposing a more efficient way to do the insertion into the temporary table?

Comment: @user714965 but I don't want to insert anything into the `zip` table, I just want to find out which codes already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to use subqueries IN ?

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Subqueries.html

would be something like this

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Zip.class, "zz");
//add restrictions for the previous dc

Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Zip.class, "z");
c.add(Subqueries.in("z.code" dc));
```

sry if I mistaken the code, its beeing a while since I dont use Hibernate

Comment: I tried using a criteria instead, the result is the same as when using HQL

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you "validate" 1000 codes against a table of 100000 records in which the code is the primary key and has a clustered index.

- Option A is not an improvement, Hibernate is going to build the same SELECT ... IN ... you could write on your own.
- Option B, as well as your current query, might fail to use the index.
- Option D might be good if you are sure the zipcodes don't change at arbitrary times, which is unlikely, or if you can recover from trying to process existing codes.
- Option C (Creating a temp table, issuing 1000 INSERT statements and joining 1000 rows against 100000 in a single SELECT) isn't competitive with just issuing 1000 simple and index-friendly queries for a single new code each:

  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Zip WHERE Zip.code = :newCode

Comment: what's Option D? Also, the real number of Zip codes involved is more like 30,000

Comment: Option D was suggested in another answer:


Option D:
Loading all existing zip codes from the database (pagination?) and make the compare in your application.


Which is rather high performance but only if the existing zip codes can be cached.

Comment: The actual numbers don't matter: as long as the number of existing codes is larger than the size of a batch of new codes, processing each of the new codes (e.g. one SELECT each, as I suggest) should be cheaper than processing each of the existing codes (e.g. loading all existing codes in a single SELECT for each batch of new codes, the worst case of Option D); both cases are definitely cheaper than quadratic processing (SELECT ... IN ... without using the index).

Answer (score 0):

There are around 45'000 Zip Codes in the US and the seem to be updated anualy. If this is an anual job, dont write it in java. Create a sql script which loads the zip codes into a a new table and write an insert statement with

`insert XXX into zip where zip.code not in (select code from  ziptemp)`

Have your operation guys run this two line SQL script once a year and dont buy yourself with this in the java code. Plus if you keep this out of java, you can basically take any approach, because no one cares if this runs for thirty minutes in offpeak times.

*divide et impera*

Comment: It's not the case that I'm simply updating a list of Zip codes and I'm also dealing with countries that have much more than 45,000 Zip codes (e.g. France, Brazil).

Comment: I didnt want to be an imperialist, acutally I am German ;.) But this makes things even more drastic. Assuming you have an online app, you really dont want to mix heavy duty batch processing on your db with your online web application. If you can do it offline or at low times, you should delegate this to operations and scripts. No matter how you are dealing with this, you are putting heavy locking on your rows and tables, which may cascade with foreign constraints to other tables causing issues with blocking inserts and updates on other business objects.

Comment: Again, this is not something that can be done in a batch process, it's a user-visible feature of the app. The user uploads a file containing a lot of zip codes and part of the processing of the file requires me to determine which are already in the DB

Comment: Then I would do it the other way around. Get all of your zip codes in a list, parse the new file, if you already have the zip code in the list, skip the line, otherwise add it to the database. A List for couple ten thousand entries (per country) is quite fast.